# Single Value for DBEngineVersion for provisioning Oracle RDS with latest patchset

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I'm looking for specific value for **DBEngineVersion for Oracle EE 19 RDS**, which will always **provision the latest Oracle 19c database**.
Right now, we've to give its value, very specific to each patch set. Is there any **generic major version value, that will always provision the latest minor version for that major version** ?

thanks,
Jitu